# Community Connector Tutorial results in "Unknown data source"

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

As a first step toward developing my own Community Connector, I have followed the Codelabs Community Connector Tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#0

However, at the final step of previewing the output in a report, the connector fails with the error:

> Unknown data source
>
> The data source associated with this component could not be loaded
>
> We were not able to find the data source associated with this component. This can happen when a data source is deleted.

See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaZm.png).

The tutorial itself is quite minimal, essentially pasting 4 code blocks and a manifest; I've repeated it twice to make sure I didn't miss anything and received the same error each time.

Comment: For me the tutorial worked, and so did my first custom connector. However when I try to add my custom connector as a data source to another report I get exactly the error you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem? There was [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/162829616) with reporting copying earlier this month that caused the issue. This has since been fixed. If it still does not work for you, try the fix mentioned in the linked issue comment.